# Robot framework - Allow popups on Chrome from specific sites

Tags: robotframework

I am using below to launch Chrome

```
${chrome options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
Call Method    ${chrome options}    add_argument    disable-extensions
Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome_extension_disabled    chrome_options=${chrome options}
```

**I need to allow popups coming from a specific sites.** Any help?
As currently, the popups is getting blocked and I am not able to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test my solution because Chrome running under ChromeDriver never blocks pop-ups (see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1291). Here is something to try:

```
${allow}=    Create Dictionary    setting=${1}
${exceptions}=    Create Dictionary    mydomain.com=${allow}
${prefs}=    Create Dictionary    profile.popups=${exceptions}
Call Method    ${chrome options}    add_experimental_option    prefs    ${prefs}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: I used below code
${chrome options}=  Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
${allow}=  Create Dictionary  setting=${1}
${exceptions}=  Create Dictionary  https://www.WebSite.com=${allow}
${prefs}= Create Dictionary  profile.popups=${exceptions}
Call Method  ${chrome options}  add_argument  disable-extensions
Call Method  ${chrome options}  add_experimental_option  prefs    ${prefs}
Create Webdriver  Chrome  chrome_extension_disabled    chrome_options=${chrome options}
But still i cannot see exception added to setting in chrome for the popups

Comment: Sorry to hear that. One alternative is using a profile that already has exceptions configured manually. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/35441094/2532697