# Chrome extension disappear every time i run my automation test script

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-extension, robotframework

I need to test Chrome extension using `Selenium Robot Framework`?

Extension is installed on the browser, but it disappears every time I run my test script.

Can anyone tell me the steps I need to follow in `Selenium Robot Framework`

Answer (score 4):

There are two approaches to this. You can instruct Chrome to install a specific extension on startup or you can use a persistent profile where an extension is installed. To get a crx file for an extension, see [Give Me CRX](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/give-me-crx/acpimoebmfjpfnbhjgdgiacjfebmmmci). See this [help topic](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142059) on creating a new profile into which you can install an extension.

```
*** Settings ***
Test Teardown     Close All Browsers
Library           Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
Install Extension On Startup
    ${chrome options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${chrome options}    add_extension    C:\\ws\\extension_2_0_2.crx
    Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${chrome options}
    Goto    https://stackoverflow.com
    Sleep    1 minute    # manually verify the extension is active

Using Saved Profile
    ${chrome options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${chrome options}    add_argument    user-data-dir\=C:\\ws\\User Data
    Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${chrome options}
    Goto    https://stackoverflow.com
    Sleep    1 minute    # manually verify the extension is active
```

The '\' after user-data-dir is to escape the '=' so Robot Framework does not interpret user-data-dir as a keyword argument name.

[Help on Chrome Options for Selenium](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities)

[Help on Create Webdriver](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Create%20Webdriver*)